# How to create mgrid in an automated way using a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict that looks like this

```
d = {'x_0_min' : 3, 'x_1_min' : 4, 'x_2_min' : 0, 'x_0_max' : 3, 'x_1_max' : 4, 'x_2_max' : 0}
```

I want to create a mesh grid, so i am using this

```
import numpy as np
x0_g, x1_g, x2_g = np.mgrid[x_0_min:x_0_max:50j, x_1_min:x_1_max:50j, x_2_min:x_2_max:50j] (1)
```

The problem is, that the `max(i)`, where `i` is the "counter" of the elements `f'x_{i}_min` and `f'x_{i}_max` in the dictionary `d` can vary.

Is there a way to automate the execution of line `(1)`, for an abstract `i` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I did it is the following:

```
mycode_left = ''
mycode_right = ' = np.mgrid['
n = 3
for i in range(0,n):
    mycode_left += f'x{i}_g'
    if i != n - 1:
        mycode_left += ', '
        
    mycode_right += f'd["x_{i}_min"]:dict_vars["x_{i}_max"]:50j'
    if i != n - 1:
        mycode_right += ', '
    else:
        mycode_right += ']'

exec(mycode_left + mycode_right)
```

So basically I created the command and then ran it using `exec()`

And `print(mycode_left + mycode_right)` returns

`x0_g, x1_g, x2_g = np.mgrid[d["x_0_min"]:dict_vars["x_0_max"]:50j, d["x_1_min"]:dict_vars["x_1_max"]:50j, d["x_2_min"]:dict_vars["x_2_max"]:50j]`